# Design rationale behind switching to non-updatable-while-open snap apps

Tags: updates, snap, design

Snap apps cannot be updated while open on Ubuntu; one gets instead a notification:

> pending update of "firefox" snap
>
> Close the app to avoid disruptions (10 days left)

To me, this seems like a serious limitation for some apps that are almost always open, especially on servers; for instance Firefox, Skype, Nextcloud, Kubernetes...

Why was that not considered a concern and a step back from the `deb` format?

Answer (score 1):

It was considered.

See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/download-snap-updates-without-applying-it-until-next-startup-or-application-launch-like-offline-updates/26768/8 for one developer explanation of all the various thorny problems involved the led to notifying the user that a refresh is needed.

The deb method isn't perfect either for several reasons.

Folks who want to get involved with solving the discussed problems are welcome. Snapd is open source.

Comment: Thanks! This explains the technical angle from the snap side, but in case someone wishes to write another answer I am also interested in the Ubuntu angle: was this considered at the moment of switching some applications from deb to snaps in the distro?

Comment: There's an invalid assumption there that most applications transition by central design; suggesting that we're somehow "pushing" snaps. Most applications actually transition for their own reasons, usually the reduced build and support requirements. For example, the Firefox transition from Deb to Snap was driven by Mozilla for their own reasons. Canonical engineers and Ubuntu volunteers merely helped make a smooth transition after the decision was already made upstream at Mozilla.

Comment: Who is "we"? Canonical? Neither your profile nor your answer mention you being affiliated with Canonical.

Comment: In any case, I have a hard time believing Ubuntu was not involved at all in the decision. Debian still has a [firefox deb](https://packages.debian.org/sid/firefox), so if the Ubuntu devs/maintainers wanted they could have kept that in their repositories. Mozilla doesn't have ultimate control on how Ubuntu maintainers use their open-source code.